# MySQL: Strange WHERE behaviour with incrementing variables

Tags: mysql, increment, where-clause

I have a table with 16 sequential rows:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),();
```

Executing the following statement, as expected, returns all rows:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x:=0) a WHERE id=(@x:=@x+1);
+----+-------+
| id | @x:=0 |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
|  2 |     0 |
|  3 |     0 |
...
```

However, the following statement, rather than returning every other row, returns **nothing**:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x:=0) a WHERE id=(@x:=@x+2);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What could explain this?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19da8/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are confused.  The code is doing exactly what you are specifying.

During the first iteration -- assuming `t` is read in order (which is not guaranteed) -- you have:

```
id = 1, @x = 2
```

Then:

```
id = 2, @x = 4
id = 3, @x = 6
```

and so on.  These values are never equal, so no rows are returned.

If you want every other row, then use `mod()`:

```
where mod(id, 2) = 1
```

Variables are not needed.

Comment: Why does it go through the table sequentially? I expected it to execute like a standalone `WHERE` statement ( e.g. on the first iteration: `WHERE id=2` ).

Comment: The variables are processed as the query is being executed.  As a general rule, the rows are generated by the `from` clause, the filters are applied in the `where`, `group by` is then applied, then `select`, and the `having`, `order by`, and `limit` clauses.

Comment: I don't see the correlation between the order of clause processing and the fact that `WHERE` steps through the table sequentially. Does the optimizer automatically decide to do so when one of the comparison terms is a variable? Executing the query with `FORCE INDEX` has no effect either.

Comment: @concat . . . I am totally missing your confusion.  MySQL looks at the "first" row in the table.  The `id` is 1.  The `@x` value starts out at zero and gets incremented to 2.  The "1" is compared to the "2" and there is no match.  So the row is not in the result set.  On the next iteration, the `id` value is 2, and `@x` is incremented to 4.  Once again, no match, so nothing in the result set.  And so on.  There is no `order by` clause, but that would make no difference because it would happen after the filtering.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. My confusion is that I don't understand why MySQL "looks" at the first row at all: executing `SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=5` uses the indexes; it's clear when `t` is much bigger but the execution time is not. I understand what's ultimately happening: it's like executing `for(int id=1,x=2; id<=len(table); id++, x+=2)` in C. But why does MySQL choose to do this instead of evaluating each iteration using the indexes until the condition can no longer be met (i.e. when @x>16)?

Comment: @concat . . . MySQL cannot use an index because it doesn't know what value to look up.  You'll need to get used to the idea of "set-based" operations, where indexes are simply methods for optimizing the query.